Plasma temperature after recombination
If I have hydrogen gas that is flash-heated by a laser into a plasma with some number density $n$, an ion temperature $T_i$, and an electron temperature $T_e$. How long does it take for the hydrogen to return to a gaseous state? Is it just determined by the recombination coefficient or are there other factors that must be considered do to the rapid formation of the plasma? What is the gas's temperature immediately  after it returns to a gas?
